# Python interpreter evaluates expression 4 < 5 to True. Why then does 4 < 5 == True return False?

Tags: python-3.x, comparison, operators

Was messing around with values and concept in interpreter and hit a logic stumbling block as 4 < 5 is True but this output is not considered equal to == True?

Answer (score 1):

From Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
>   comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
>   a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

From this specification is `4 < 5 == True` equal to `4 < 5 and 5 == True` (and from [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python it equals to `(4 < 5) and (5 == True)`) where `4 < 5` is `True`, but `5 == True` is `False`. So `True and False` is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3: `4 < 5 == True` is equivalent to `4 < 5 and 5 == True`, which evaluates to `False` because `5 != True`.

Note that `<` and `==` have the same precedence.

Doc for reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 4<5
True
>>> 4<5 == True
False
>>> (4<5) == True
True
>>>
```

I hope this clears your doubt. `4<5 == True` is evaluating as `4<5 and 5 == True` which overall returns False as `4<5` is True, but, `5 == True` is False. This is due to `<` and `==` having the same level of precedence.

Comment: Thank you Jay. So is this a formatting or order of precedence issue or something else? Not to make a mountain out of a molehill but True and True == True is True , True and False == False is also True.

Comment: This is an precedence and associativity of operators issue. Best way to avoid this, is by explicitly adding paranthesis.